# Multiple Contextual Filters

Tags: views

I am trying to filter views output using Parameters from url with views contextual filter.
There are two fields on the content type :

- 1.field_sku
- 2.field_width

I simply added the contextual filter for the first one , but as i add the second filter it doesn't work.
Is it posibble to add multiple contextual filter to a view?

Comment: Of-course you can add multiple contextual filters. Could you please add more information about how you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because how you get them,contextual filter usually get from url and when you have 2 , you should have 2 parameter in url , as example  it should something like "mysite.com/3/reza",
this is one step, another step is that you  specified in your contextual filter that which arg is for this filter(**put your default value in raw value form url,then you see path componet**), (in my sample 3 is arg(0) and reza is arg(1) ) and if you  observe this note it work for you correctly.

Comment: What if I have to get all media entities that uses a specific fid (e.g 10) and it could be either image or document media entities and both type has different fields as field_image and field_document? I have the URL like "media/find-by-file-id/%" then how can get all entities using  multiple contextual filters like "field_image:target_id" and "field_document:target_id"?

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't well described, but i think this is your solution:

Querying the configured multiple contextual filter isn't working as i expected first and I spent lot of time to figure out why, then finally the solution was found:

Instead of `Content: The name of Taxonomy (taxonomy_vocabulary_#)` you need to select `Content: Has taxonomy term ID` *Contextual filter* and enable *Allow multiple values* to able to use multiple values in the form of `1+2+3` (for `OR`) or `1,2,3` (for `AND`).
If You have another *Contextual filter* configured, you can separate the query with "/".